# URL rewrite htaccess

Tags: php, apache, url-rewriting

I have a small website where I have wrote some rules

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^[!/.]*([A-Za-z0-9]+)/?$ /index.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

This redirects all of my links to `example.com/index.php`. Whereas I want them to redirect all the URLs with one directory `example.com/dir` to be redirected to this link `example.com/index.php`, and URLs with two directories, `example.com/dir1/dir2` should redirect to `example.com/index2.php`, and rest should not be redirected.

Comment: add two rewrite rules with different regular expression. do u need help with regex?

Comment: Probably better off on webmasters.stackexchange.com?

Comment: Some ideas: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the below code .. i'll explain it a little ..

http://www.example.com/customdir/index/1/

customdir = Your Sub Directory

index = index.php

1 = Your id

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule customdir/(\w+)/?(\d+)?/? customdir/$1.php?id=$2
```

Comment: thx for your reply, in my case urls are only suppose to have directory names i.e. mysite.com/abc (on directory) or may be mysite.com/abc/cde (two directories), I am suppose to make directory one as query string variable 1 and directory two as query string variable two please if you can give some idea of that (directory names are random as directories are being created at runtime - that is main confusion for me)